# Open all images on page with magnific popup

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I want to enable magnific popup on all images on my page. I do not want to alter the DOM (surround my image tags with anchors like suggested in the [documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#initializing-popup)).

My DOM is something like

```
<div id="content">
  <img src="img/mw1.png" class="figure-img img-fluid">
  <img src="img/mw2.png" class="figure-img img-fluid">
  <img src="img/mw3.png" class="figure-img img-fluid">
</div>
```

And the JS I have:

```
var $imgs = [];
$('img').each(function(idx) {
  var obj = {
    src: $(this).attr('src')
  }
  $imgs.push(obj);
  var elem = $(this);
  $(this).click(function() {
    console.log('clicked on img', idx);
    $('#content').magnificPopup('open', idx);
  });
});

$('#content').magnificPopup({
  items: $imgs,
  type: 'image',
  gallery: {
    enabled: true
  },
});
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/A2yRWr4bDi
No matter which image i click, always, the first gets opend. I want it exactly like it is, just with the difference that the clicked image gets opened first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's a bug in the `magnific-popup` code where it never passes that index along.

In v1.1.0 jquery.magnific-popup.js, line 931 (unmin'd), add:

```
itemOpts.index = index;  // add this line
mfp._openClick({mfpEl:items}, jqEl, itemOpts);  <-- before this line
```

and it will work fine.

However, this will mean you'll need a local copy of the file and min it yourself (locally) until the author can update.

Comment: Wow. You are a true detective! I wonder however if I am the first with this issue.